# Double Icons coming while using dangerouslySetInnerHtml

Tags: reactjs

I have a react code where i am trying to create fontawesome icons by passing div content in string format to react component , but while rendering it creates copy icons one with hyperlink other without hyperlink , here is the code snippet where i am using dangerouslySetInnerHtml

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.createAllIconsAndHyperLinks() }} />
```

**createAllIconsAndHyperLinks()** method return content as :

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.com/singh_kshitij"><i class="fab fa-github"/></a>
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://twitter.com/ikshitijsingh"><i class="fab fa-twitter"/></a>
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/7088832/kshitij-singh"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"/></a>
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ikshitijsingh/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"/></a>
```

here's how the thing is getting rendered : 
[Click and Open to See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe178.png)

Actually seeing duplicate icons , one with link and other without link . What could be the problem if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
<a target="_blank" class="fab fa-github" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.com/singh_kshitij">
```

Yould could add some css in order to style the link.